# Spring Security | Ajax based REST calls - Send authentication information

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, rest, spring-security

Folks,

I am working on this application that uses Spring Security and makes AJAX calls to some REST resources using jQuery.
Here is the scenario:

Inside my view (JSP) I have the following:

```
  var prodReq = JSON.stringify( ({'platformVersionRequest' : {'skuCode':skuCode,'customerGuid': customerGuid, 'storeCode' : storeCode} }));        
    request = jQuery.ajax({ //Start AJAX request
                     headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                     },
                     type: "POST",  
                     url: "/webservices/resource/pd",  
                     dataType:'json',
                     data: prodReq,
                     success: function(data){
                        ....
                        ....
                    },
                    error:function(){}  
               });
```

Now, the page hosting the above snippet has been secured using Spring security providing a 'ROLE' and 'requires-channel' as per the following:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/resource/pd/**" access="ROLE_CUSTOMER" requires-channel="https" />
```

Now, the problem I am facing is that everytime I access this page, Spring security kicks in and shows the login page (which is expected and what I want). However, as soon as I login, my  REST resource gets called and shows a Basic Auth popup to the user which I do not want.

It seems the Ajax requests cannot understand that the resource has been successfully authenticated because, once I enter my correct credentials, I am not prompted for the password.

Just to add on, I have made a few REST calls using the backend JAVA code where we pass on the username and password as base 64 encoded string in the header. Is something on the same lines required here? If yes, how do I get the authentication details from Spring security in Javascript?

Would appreciate any inputs on this.

Edit 1:
Security config:

```
  <http realm="Web Services"  auto-config="false"  entry-point-ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/resource/pd/**" access="ROLE_CUSTOMER" requires-channel="https" />
    ....
    ....
    </http>

    <port-mappings>
      <port-mapping http="${ep.ws.port.http}" https="${ep.ws.port.https}" />
    </port-mappings>
    <custom-filter position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="basicAuthenticationFilter" />  
  </http>
  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customerAuthenticationDao">
      <password-encoder ref="sha256PasswordEncoder">
        <salt-source ref="customerSaltSource"/>
      </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>

     <authentication-provider user-service-ref="cmUserAuthenticationDao">
      <password-encoder ref="cmPasswordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

  <beans:bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter"
          class="com.abc.xyz.web.authentication.www.ExtLdapBasicAuthenticationFilter"
          p:authenticationManager-ref="customerAuthenticationManager"
          p:authenticationEntryPoint-ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          p:customerService-ref="customerService" />

  <beans:bean id="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="com.abc.xyz.security.impl.PlainTextBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint" p:realmName="Web Services"/>

  <beans:bean id="customerAuthenticationDao" parent="txProxyTemplate">
    <beans:property name="target">
      <beans:bean class="com.abc.xyz.rest.security.impl.CustomerUserDetailsServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="customerService" ref="customerService" />
        <beans:property name="storeHelper" ref="storeHelper" />
      </beans:bean>
     </beans:property>
  </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="customerAuthenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="ldapAuthenticationProvider" />
            <beans:ref local="customerAuthenticationProvider" />
            <beans:ref local="cmUserAuthenticationProvider" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    .......
    .......
    .......

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Could you post your Security Config?

Comment: @s.kwiotek Posted relevant portion of Security config.. Just to add on to my question, I have two separate projects (storefront and webservices). The storefront project holds the application pages (JSP's) (and has a separate security config file, not posted here). The JSP's inside this project call the REST services hosted inside the webservices project (Security config posted) (both projects have separate WAR files)

Comment: I am confused you say that a login page is shown, but your security config above has a basic authentication filter defined. Are you by chance enabling both, by explicity adding the basic authentication filter.

Comment: @thedoctor Probably I was not very clear in my question.The login page is shown when I access the secured JSP file (hosted in the storefront project). Accessing secured REST resources (hosted inside webservices project) shows the basic authentication popup (which I don't want)

Comment: Guys, would appreciate any inputs here.